# Can I blur the entire site except for some items

Tags: javascript, html, css

We have a large application where we want to blur the entire site except for a few items during a walkthrough. As if it is an overlay.

We have explored things such as:
1. Apply blur to the body, but that means all underlaying items will be blurred.
2. Using html2canvas to create a copy in a canvas, however this is too performance intensive.

We can not do large dom manipulations nor heavy jQuery use due to our clients being on slow machines often without graphics cards and the size of the application.

Any suggestions?

Edit: I should also add that we only require it to work in webkit browsers.

Comment: Slow machines without graphics card - just don't blur it. Rather highlight what you want by putting a semi-transparent dark overlay over everything else.

Comment: Put all the general items in one div, then the items you don't want blurred in a extra div and absolutely position them. Keep in mind this really should only be used if this demo doesn't need to be structurally accurate.

Comment: @KevinPei I understand that I can do it that way, however it doesn't create the effect I am looking for.

Comment: @TheHamstring it is a single page application, it is far too large to move into one div unfortunately.

Comment: @Ipetren, can you not move the elements out into their own div or even just on their own outside your main container or are there too many items that need to be unblurred?

Comment: It would break the model of the SPA framework we have developed, and is in that case a hack as supposed to a clean solution. That is why we cannot do it. Technically we can, philosophically we cannot.

Answer (score 1):

Simply toggle a blur class. [See  JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FJ7n4/2/).

```
<style>
.blur { 
    opacity: 0.4; 
}
.blur p {
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
.blur img {
    -webkit-filter: blur(3px);        
    filter: blur(3px);
}
</style>

<script>
$(function(){
    $('.box').hover(function () {
        $('.box').addClass('blur');
        $(this).removeClass('blur');
    });
});    
</script>

<div class="box blur">
    <p>A</p>
    <img src="example.png">
</div>
<div class="box">
    <p>B</p>        
</div>
```

Source: http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/ItemBlur/

Comment: Given that it is a single page application, which is rather large, I don't think moving everything into a different div is going to work due to bindings and the amount of dom manipulation

Comment: I see how this can work. It would mean to apply the blur class to all major containers on the site if there is not only one. Have the walkthrough and the selected item moved outside of those containers for the time being. The only problem I have for it is that there's quite a lot of dom manipulation going on and a rather hack-like solution

Comment: Adding and removing a class is not a lot of dom manipulation, what are you basing that claim on? And what about the above is hack-like? I can add JS benchmarks to show how quick this is compared to using a blur framework. I doubt you find a solution that is much faster.

Comment: Because it is a rather large application, the above is not a very clean implementation. It would be fine in a smaller site, but the manipulations it would require for moving elements out of their original position breaks the modular nature of the SPA framework we have developed. That is why in our case it would be more of a hack-like solution.

Comment: No elements are moved in the above code. Did you look at the JSFiddle? Only a single css class is added and removed.

Comment: Well, yes, in the simple example. Let me see if I can explain this without confusing it. It is a large application. Some elements that should be clear are children of elements that needs to be blurred. Because of that, they would have to be moved or cloned to a different container which doesn't have blur applied to it if the above method where to be used.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah you can do this with a plugin name `Foggy`..

Check [this.](http://nbartlomiej.github.io/foggy/)..It will help you

Comment: It seems to be a helping tool for moving classes around on the DOM, but still as a library introduces quite a lot of manipulation of the dom as supposed to just using CSS. Not quite what we are looking for but thanks, may come in useful for other projects

Answer (score 1):

I might be missing the point here, but if you ONLY require support for webkit browsers, then why not just use the -webkit-filter:

```
nav, header, main, footer {
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(1) blur(5px);
}
*:hover {
  -webkit-filter: none;
}
```

It's pretty responsive for me on my old MacBook Pro and the cool thing is that you have so many options to add grayscale, adjustments for brightness, saturation, contrast, opacity, etc.  And, it would be fairly simple and lightweight to script a demo in jQuery for your walkthrough, since all you would need to do is remove or add the -webkit-filter to your desired elements.

### [DEMO >](http://www.bootply.com/G9LBUCNQEQ)

(I just reused a Bootply I had as an example since it had a fair amount of content).

Comment: This would fail in IE/Firefox. This is nice if you only need to support webkit browsers.

Comment: I see. But correct me if I am wrong, this only works for hover? Because it hovers all objects below it can apply the filter: none; to all of them. It wouldn't work by doing something like applying a class called nofilter and define it in css with -webkit-filter:none;

Comment: Updated the demo.  If it's possible to group the elements you want to blur, then you don't have to use the universal selector and the hover option might be more suitable for your walk-through.  If not, maybe it helps someone else in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your browser requirements are, or how archaic the technology you're developing for is, but you might check out [blur.js](http://blurjs.com/) I could see it not being too heavy, dependent on how much content you have.

Worst case you could probably put a full-width, full-height div between your active area and the rest of the site using absolute positioning and a z-index, and then run blur on that so that the active area has the appearance of being the only unblurred thing.

Comment: Our requirements are webkit browsers only, and it can take the blur filter however no animations given the no GPU matter. 

It is a larger big application, and that is why I am worried blur.js may not work either.

Your last solution is what we have, however it doesn't allow us to do any blur, only overlay.

Comment: I assume CSS3 filters are out of the question since the GPU is so poor, then?

[I guess this is worth a look if anything](http://jsfiddle.net/danielfilho/KxWRA/)

Comment: Actually, it seems to render the -webkit-filters- rather well as long as there is no animation. The issue there is with it is that it applies to all child elements, and we cannot move the entire DOM to a different div for blurring

Comment: You might try combining that with the div overlay? Or if you're worried about the blur cascading downward, I would just apply a `-webkit-filter: none; ` to the successive child elements that contain more DOM content. At least that way you're preventing the style from exploding all the way down to the innermost nodes. Forgive me if I'm not 100% understanding your requirements! x.x

Comment: That would be a perfect solution except that applying -webkit-filter: none; actually doesn't do anything, the overlaying filter still creates the blur it seems like

Comment: My assumption is that you have an absolutely positioned div that acts as a transparent overlay over the entire viewport that you can run `-webkit-filter: blur` on. I think you could maybe (through js) apply a class that gives relative positioning to an element on the page that is currently user-viewable and give it a higher z-index so it a) doesn't move from its originally rendered location and b) is above the blur div. Is there anything I'm missing here?

Comment: To illustrate my idea, here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Morklympious/jDL64/)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
The only solution I found was to have a transparent layer over the content with a hole in it.

```
.layer{
    position:fixed;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    top: 20px;
    left: 20px;
    box-shadow : 0 0 0 1000px red;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zLYjA/
It's a good solution if you have a slow machine. But you need to do a bit of work to determine the position of the element you want to show.

Comment: The problem with this solution is that it is merely an overlay which we can do with things such as z-index and a covering div. That's not the problem. The problem is that I am after a blurring effect such as this one http://codepen.io/lpetren/pen/ervBw

Comment: I looked for hours to do this.
Blurring effect is nearly impossible to do without cloning DOM applying overflow and blurring elements.

Comment: I've reached that conclusion a couple of times the past 12 hours, but I seem to have a slight bit of hope left

Answer (score 0):

i am giving a simple approach for creating a modal.

You can do this by blurring all the items except the items you don't want to be.
Float those items over the blurred ones with higher `z-index`

for ex:

html:

```
<div class="blur">../*items to be blured */..</div>
<div class=floated-item">../*items not to be blured */..</div>
```

CSS:

```
  .blur{
    opacity:0.4;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
  }
  .floated-item{
    z-index:999;
    position:fixed;
    margin-top:10%;
    margin-left:10%;
   }
```

Comment: This is more of a lay-over approach which we don't have any issues achieving. We were looking for a possible solution to get an effect such as filter: blur(x);, but it seems like that is not possible in an efficient and clean enough way that we need

Comment: I think it is not possible but you can use photoshop to create translucent filter with different blur intensities and using it here as div background

Comment: @lpetren you can use css filters (Blur) but these are under development. Please have a look at [link](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/filters/understanding-css/)

Comment: as you can see in the other comments throughout the post, that doesn't really work for the scenario. Blur is what I want to be able to use, however it doesn't work just as an overlay. It only affects the layers and sub layers it is applied to. The problem with that is that we need some sub layers not to have it applied to, and you cannot reverse it for some items. Moreover, the size of the application and the nature of a modular framework is against applying blur to the entire dom except for affected items as that would break the overall model of a modular SPA application